# react-native this.setState not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know there's already a similar question but there's no code shared in there.

Under `navbarChanged()` > if condition, I'm doing a `this.setState`. This is of type `HomeTab` but `setState` doesn't seem to be working.

Any clues/pointers?

```js
class HomeTab extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.setState({
      isNavBarHidden: false
    });
  }

  updatePosition(lastPosition) {
  }

  navbarChanged() {
    console.log("received navbar changed event", AppStore.navbarVisible());

    if (AppStore.navbarVisible()) {
      StatusBarIOS.setHidden(false)
      this.setState({ isNavBarHidden: false})
      // this.state.isNavbarHidden is still true here
      this.render();
    }
    else {
      StatusBarIOS.setHidden(true);
      this.setState({ isNavBarHidden: true});
      this.render();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppStore.addNavbarChangeListener( this.navbarChanged.bind(this) );
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    StatusBarIOS.setHidden(false)
    this.setState({ isNavBarHidden: false });
  }
}
```

And here's my render() code:

```js
  render() {
    return (
        <NavigatorIOS style={styles.container}
            navigationBarHidden={this.state.isNavBarHidden}
            ref="navigator"
            initialRoute={{
              title: 'Foo',
              component: HomeScreen,
              passProps: { parent: this }
            }}
        />
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Don't explicitly call `render`. React will automatically do a re-render when state or props change, so there's no need for this. Also, where is your actual `render` method?

As for your problem well, `setState` is asynchronous and so trying to work with state directly after a `setState` call won't work as the update won't necessarily have run. Instead you can use the second argument to `setState` which is a callback:

```
this.setState({ myVal: 'newVal'}, function() {
    // do something with new state
});
```

This will be triggered after state has been set and after the component has been re-rendered.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. `setState` being asynchronous answers this question. I have updated my code with my render method(). I'll get rid of render() ; what you suggested makes sense. I'm still confused though why my navigationbar is not showing back (but the titlebar is).

Comment: WOW thanks - I had no idea even reading over and over the docs that setState is async - FAR FROM IT many online tuts say the UI will render after calling this - it doesn't immediately and your answer helped me massively. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Instead of setState, use state as an instance member of the es6 class. the function setState can be called later own to ensure necessary re-renders.

```
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      isNavBarHidden: false
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also update the state in the eventHandlers and listen to `componentWillReceiveProps` for code that you need to run after the state changes.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps,nextState){
  if(this.state.myVar === nextState.myVar){
    return;
  }
  // TODO perform changes on state change
}
```

I think it is more optimal than solution given by `Colin Ramsay` above as all above logic would run before `render` gets called.

Comment: this lifecycle method is now deprecated I believe, `getDerivedStateFromProps` is usually recommended as a replacement, but that will not work in this case since its a `static` lifecycle method and you are referencing `this` inside of it.